# Using handlebars to filter specific products from a JSON object?

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

Kind of a weird and specific question but here I go.

I can currently pull all my products through YAML and through some really brute-force methods, I would be able to sort the product out by custom fields.

I have a multiple choice wizard the user has to fill and in the end, I get an object that looks something like this:

```
{
  stoneType: ['Granite', 'Quartz', 'Glass'],
  stoneFinish: ['Polished', 'Honed'],
  stoneConcern: ['Floor Care'],
  labels: ['Daily Cleaning', 'Stain Removal']
}
```

I can't (or at least I don't know how) to get this data into my HTML to use the data stored in my YAML code and render the specific products.

I believe I can solve this issue if I were able to pass the array of products into javascript using some sort of handlebars helper(?) but Bigcommerce doesn't allow for custom helper functions.

I read online that you can bypass this by installing handlebars but that is not working for me.

When I installed handlebars through NPM, I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/stencil/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/dist/theme-bundle.main.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there a way for me to get custom helper functions working or another possible idea to sort & filter the products?

Thank you, appreciate the help.

EDIT: I have also tried manually downloading Handlebars.js including the file but I get the error Handlebars is not defined. I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Can you share a little more detail about what your end goal would look like? Are you trying to do something like filter out all products that match stoneFinish: Polished in the context of a category page, or is this a filter for all of the products in the store?

Comment: Thanks for replying @KarenWhite, the end goal would be something like a modal popping up with the products that have the specified values... or maybe routing to a custom page and showing the products there.(if possible). All of those keys (stoneType, stoneFinish, etc) are custom fields and not categories. This would be a filter for all products in the store.

Comment: I'm not sure Handlebars is really going to be the right tool for the job here (and it's not possible to install your own version of Handlebars on top of what's built into Stencil). You're looking at a pure JavaScript solution if you want to do this on the frontend, but performance-wise, it's probably better to build out middleware using something like AWS Lambda to filter and retrieve products via the catalog API.

Comment: @KarenWhite Interesting... I never messed with anything AWS provided but I guess this is a good opportunity. How difficult would you say it is to integrate Lambda?

Comment: Hey @syn The architecture is pretty straightforward with Lambda, but there can be some complexity in the filtering itself. The basic process could look like this: Create an endpoint with Amazon API Gateway that when called, triggers your Lambda function to run. The Lambda function would essentially be making a request to the BigCommerce API for product data, do some processing on that data, and then return the information you want back to the storefront. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/going-serverless-how-to-run-your-first-aws-lambda-function-in-the-cloud-d866a9b51536